# Is there an equivalent for data frames to the following code for vectors: unsampled.vector <- original.vector[-sampled.vector,]

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

I sampled a data frame from another data frame using:

```
sample_df <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf), 10), ]
```

How do I get the unsampled portion of `mydf`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably save the value of the sample, then you can use negative indexing just as you would in a vector:

```
sample_df <- mydf[s <- sample(nrow(mydf),10),]
remainder_df <- mydf[-s,]
```

Or more comprehensibly

```
s <- sample(nrow(mydf),10)
sample_df <- mydf[s,]
remainder_df <- mydf[-s,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ben's advice is the way I would go, but if there haven't been any changes to either `data.frame`, then you should be able to get the alternate subset via the `rownames` of each `data.frame`:

```
 mydf[!rownames(mydf) %in% rownames(sample_df), ]
```

---

Simple demo:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, v1 = letters[1:10])
sample_df <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf), 5), ]
sample_df
#   ID v1
# 3  3  c
# 4  4  d
# 5  5  e
# 7  7  g
# 2  2  b
mydf[!rownames(mydf) %in% rownames(sample_df), ]
#    ID v1
# 1   1  a
# 6   6  f
# 8   8  h
# 9   9  i
# 10 10  j
```